# Fixing zsh prompt

Tags: zsh, prompt

I installed Arch Linux and migrated my .zshrc over and am using the bart prompt theme. I see the normal theme on the first line (hostname; last command run; pwd; and time) but on the next line is:  `\[\][ \[\]hostname \[\]\W\[\] \[\]]\[\]# \[\]`
where $hostname is my actual hostname.
I renamed the files in my `/etc/zsh` to `backup.zshrc` `backup.zprofile` and `backup.keephack`. The prompt on my other computer is uncluttered so I know it's not something in the `~/.zshrc` that I migrated over.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bash prompt, so a bash setting has somehow leaked to zsh. All common shells use the `PS1` variable as the primary prompt, but they use different formats. Since `PS1` has different meanings to different programs, it should never be an environment variable, only a variable in each program that uses it (bash, zsh, etc.). Unfortunately, many distributions ship default files that set `PS1` in the environment, often in `/etc/profile`.

Zsh uses more than `PS1` to build its prompt. I don't know how your prompt theme works, but it's plausible that it combines multiple elements including `PS1`. Because `PS1` is being set in a way it's shouldn't, zsh ends up picking a stray bash setting.

Therefore a likely fix is to add `unset PS1` in your `.zshrc`. Depending on how the prompt theme works, you may or may not need to do that before setting the prompt theme.